# Dataset parsing for Apache Open NLP

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, opennlp

I found out that apache open NLP has a document categorizer with a maximum entropy algorithm which can be used for sentiment analysis.

With the below code, I was able to successfully train a classifier which can predict basic text for their sentiment.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import opennlp.tools.doccat.DoccatModel;
import opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentCategorizerME;
import opennlp.tools.doccat.DocumentSampleStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.InputStreamFactory;
import opennlp.tools.util.MarkableFileInputStreamFactory;
import opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream;


public class OpenNLPCategorizer {
    private DoccatModel model;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OpenNLPCategorizer twitterCategorizer = new OpenNLPCategorizer();
        twitterCategorizer.trainModel();
        twitterCategorizer.classifyNewTweet("This movie is good");
    }

    private void trainModel() {
        InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory;
        try {
            inputStreamFactory = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(
                    new File("datasets/en-sent.csv"));
            ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(inputStreamFactory, "UTF-8");
            ObjectStream sampleStream = new DocumentSampleStream(lineStream);

            model = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", sampleStream);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void classifyNewTweet(String tweet) {
        DocumentCategorizerME myCategorizer = new DocumentCategorizerME(model);
        double[] outcomes = myCategorizer.categorize(tweet);
        String category = myCategorizer.getBestCategory(outcomes);

        if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            System.out.println("The tweet is positive :) ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The tweet is negative :( ");
        }
    }
}
```

The dataset I used is very simple consisting of 10 lines.

My questions

1) How to prepare the dataset present [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) i.e., `polarity v2.0` for training ? Or in general how to prepare datasets for OpenNLP. I could not find any guide online.

2) How to verify the accuracy ? The Naive Bayes on Apache Spark can split the dataset into 70:30. How can I split the dataset in such a way so that the accuracy can be tested?